# Can you create an expression, for use in google docs, for finding line breaks that are NOT using the 'Normal text' format?

Tags: expression, google-docs

I'm a novice at expressions and I've failed to find what I'm looking for on the internet.  Not even sure if this possible, but hoping it is and that some kind soul can help me out. :)

My goal is have an expression I can use that will find any blank line in a google doc that is NOT using the 'Normal text' format.  For example:  If a blank line is using "Heading 3" or "Heading 2", etc, this expression should find it.  (If empty row AND format is NOT 'Normal Text')

Again, not even sure if it's possible to build an expressing that finds this exact issue, but it'd save me a TON of time if I could.  Thank you for your time! :)

PS - For those that are wondering, a large part of my job is reviewing documents.  I identify issues, leave suggestions or comments, then return the document for the author to clean up.  My plan is to give this expression to the document authors, so they can clean up issue like this quickly and easily and save us both a lot of time.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't match a word based on it's attributes(heading, normal text, etc.) just by using a regular expression. This might be possible when using Google Apps Script though. You can try and explore Google Apps Script and see if it will solve your problem.

Comment: Hey Jason E I appreciate your help on this.  I was afraid that was case, since my searching of the internet yielded no results.  Thank you again sir!